# Can't turn on plantuml-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, installation, major-mode, plantuml

I am on Emacs 24.3.1.  I installed the [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) version of [`plantuml-mode`](https://github.com/zwz/plantuml-mode) via

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `plantuml-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

When I try to turn on `plantuml-mode` for a buffer, I get the following error:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

Trying to find additional installation instructions I looked at the "Commentary" section in the `plantuml-mode.el` source, but there it only says to `require` the package, and I am doing that.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a bit more digging I found the solution to this problem: `plantuml-mode` won't run unless the variable `plantuml-jar-path` is set to a non-`nil` value. Fairly obvious in hindsight, but still easy to get bit by since it isn't mentioned explicitly (at least not anywhere that I could find). For best results, the variable should point to the location of the `plantuml.jar` file in your file system. In my case:

```
(setq plantuml-jar-path "/opt/plantuml/plantuml.jar")
```

Hope this helps someone else at some point.